# about c++ conversion : no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘[some_class]' to ‘[some_class]&’

Tags: c++

I'm working on C++, and had an error that I didn't know the exact reason. I've found the solution, but still want to know why.

```
    class Base
    {
        public:
               void something(Base& b){}
    };

    int main()
    {
        Base b;
        b.something(Base());
        return 0;           
    }
```

when I compile the code, I got this following error :

```
abc.cpp:12:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::something(Base)’
abc.cpp:12:20: note: candidate is:
abc.cpp:6:7: note: void Base::something(Base&)
abc.cpp:6:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Base’ to ‘Base&’
```

but when I replaced b.something(Base()) into

```
Base c;
b.something(c);
```

the error is gone, I'm wondering why??? aren't they have the same type? It only matters how I write it, but the meaning should be the same???

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Seems like a valid and useful question - upvoted to counter the unexplained downvote.

Comment: @CompuChip people like you make this community a lot better.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are passing a temporary `Base` object here:

```
b.something(Base());
```

but you try to bind that to a non-const lvalue reference here:

```
void something(Base& b){}
```

This is not allowed in standard C++. You need a `const` reference.

```
void something(const Base& b){}
```

When you do this:

```
Base c;
b.something(c);
```

you are not passing a temporary. The non-const reference binds to `c`.

Comment: +1 good point on the fact this is allowed for const references

Comment: Maybe also state that with vc this might compile (we noticed this as we migrated to g++ :D )

Comment: @Paranaix VS doesn't allow it either if you have the right compiler flags set (`/W4` and `/WX`)

Comment: Thats why I wrote 'might'. As it is an extension you can of course deactivate it. Although this breaks the windows headers AFAIK as they arent standart conform either.

Comment: This answer should be updated to catch up with c++11, the solution can be add a function with r-value reference.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you attempt to pass a (non-const)reference to a temporary as argument to a function which is not possible. In the second case you pass a reference to an existing object which is perfectly valid.