# Templatized child not accepted as parent when using variant

Tags: c++, templates, variant

I'm trying to execute a very simple abstract factory with templatized arguments, and am receiving an error I can't get to the bottom of.

**The core issue is that, outside of a template, a variant type accepts any of the members of its union, but inside of a template, this deduction seems to be failing.**  I can't find the bug in my construction that's leading to this occurring.

The minimal producing code is as follows; just by removing templates, it compiles just fine

```cpp
class A{};
class B{};

using AB = std::variant<A,B>;

template <class T1, class T2>
class Parent
{
};

class Child : public Parent<A,B>
{
public:
    static Parent<A,B>* build(){ return new Child(); }
};


template <class T1, class T2>
using Fn = std::function<Parent<T1,T2> *(void)>;

using ParentFn = Fn<AB,AB>;

int main()
{
        // in a factory, we might say
        // map<string, ParentFn> m; m["key"] = &Child::build;
        // but for MRE I'll just do assignment
        ParentFn tmp = &Child::build; // does just fine without templates, crashes horribly with

    return 0;
}
```

As written, however, it spits out the compilation error

```
main.cpp:32:24: error: conversion from ‘Parent<A, B>* (*)()’ to non-scalar type ‘ParentFn {aka std::function<Parent<std::variant<A, B>, std::variant<A, B> >*()>}’ requested
         ParentFn tmp = &Child::build; // does just fine without templates, crashes horribly with
```

---

I believe that the issue isn't  [an lvalue/rvalue issue like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247525/about-c-conversion-no-known-conversion-for-argument-1-from-some-class-to), since the method being referenced is static (but we can pull it out and force it to be an lvalue without resolving this error, too). [GCC is known to have some bugs with aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253473/variadic-template-aliases-as-template-arguments) but I don't see how they'd be relevant here since I think they're isolated to variadics; I'm using g++-7.1, -std=c++17

Why isn't the compiler able to accept type `A` where type `variant<A,B>` is requested? Isn't that the whole point of variants? For example, `AB ab = A();` or `AB ab = B();` are both valid, though that might just be clever overloading of the `=` operator?

Am I misusing variant, std::function, templates, aliases, or all of the above?

---

As proof that the problem is related to the templates, the code without templates compiles as:

```cpp
class Parent
{
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    static Parent* build(){ return new Child(); }
};

using Fn = std::function<Parent *(void)>;

using ParentFn = Fn;

int main()
{
        ParentFn tmp = &Child::build; // does just fine without templates, crashes horribly with

    return 0;
}
```

My basis for believing that std variant might be substitute for either of the individual types is the trivial test

```cpp
AB ab1 = A();
ab1 = B();
```

both seem to be acceptable.

Comment: `Parent<A, B>` is completely unrelated to `Parent<C, D>`, `C` and `D` being `std::variant<A, B>` doesn't change that.

Comment: Can you show non-templated code that does work?

Comment: @kmdreko I thought `D` being `std::variant<A,B>` meant that `D` could be used as either `A` or `B` - the sort of basic example is `AB ab = A();` and `AB ab = B();` both resolve without problem - is this just clever overloading over the equality operator and unrelated to the typing issue?

Comment: @n.m. the exact same code without the templates works (literally just removing templates from that block). Would you like me to copy it below in the question? I thought it would just add noise, but I can put it there if you think it'll be informative

Comment: Please save everyone the completely unnecessary effort of trying to read your mind. Have code? Post it, not instructions to recreate it

Comment: @n.m. ah definitely don't want to only get advice from mind readers. I figured that people would prefer a minimal example of what breaks, but evidently it was unclear what the working alternative was - I've added it now for clarity

Comment: An `A` or `B` can be *converted* to a `std::variant<A, B>` but that's where it's convenience ends. It is just a class with no special provisions from a language perspective. So `A*` can't be converted to `std::variant<A, B>*` nor can `SomeTemplate<A>` be converted to `SomeTemplate<std::variant<A, B>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deobfuscating your code I think what you are trying to do comes down to attempting the following.

Works

```
#include <variant>

class A{};
class B{};

using AB = std::variant<A,B>;


AB * Foo();

typedef AB*(*Fn)();

int main()
{
    Fn f = &Foo;

}
```

Doesn't work

```
#include <variant>

class A{};
class B{};

using AB = std::variant<A,B>;


AB * Foo();

typedef A*(*Fn)();

int main()
{
    Fn f = &Foo;

}
```

> error: invalid conversion from 'AB* (*)()' {aka 'std::variant* (*)()'} to 'Fn' {aka 'A* (*)()'} [-fpermissive]

which if you want to reduce it further is attempting to convert `std::variant<A,B> *` to `A*` which will not work.

In fact you cannot even convert `A*` to  `std::variant<A,B> *`. The only conversion allowed is `A` to `std::variant<A,B>` or `B` to `std::variant<A,B>`

https://godbolt.org/z/Xwbsou

Comment: The "convert std::variant<A,B> * to A* which will not work" is what is throwing me off - why won't it? I thought `variant<A,B>` was just a union of the too, and could be substituted for any of its parts (this misnuderstanding might be my mistake). For example, we could write `AB ab = A();` or `AB ab = B();` and the compiler wouldn't complain.. is that just clever overloading of the `=` operator?

Comment: Think about it!! If AB happens to hold a ``B`` then you want to store it in an ``A`` how is that meant to work? ``AB`` can store ``A`` or ``B``. ``A`` can store only ``A`` and ``B`` can store only ``B``.

Comment: thank you for spelling it out for me. I think I decided that variants were magic multitypes instead of slight sugar on top of unions :(  (I think your comment would be useful as part of the answer, too, but up to you)